# Xamarin iOS - Get all images from Bundle or folder

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios, resources, bundle

How can I get all images (or filenames) from the Bundle or from the resources folder?
I already tried it with

```
NSBundle.GetPathsForResources(".png", "Resources/Images/Various");
```

but this only returns **null**.

Answer (score 0):

Try `MonoTouch.Foundation.NSFileManager.GetDirectoryContentRecursive` or `GetDirectoryContent` Method.

Comment: Still returns null

Comment: Is there really a folder "Resources/Images/Various", and image files in that folder?

Comment: Sure, there is.

Comment: NSError object is nil or not?

Comment: no, it gives me the error "The file “Various” couldn’t be opened because there is no such file."

Comment: Try MonoTouch.Foundation.NSBundle.ResourcePath, and add "Images/Various", then use this string to retrieve file.

Comment: Or use GetDirectoryContentRecursive and "Resources/Images", without "Various"

Comment: Second approach returns null and the error is "The file “Images” couldn’t be opened because there is no such file."
I don't know how to write the first one